# Use builder pattern to create exceptions?

Tags: java, exception, builder

I have an exception in my java code that has several properties which would be passed into the constructor. Therefore I thought it would be nice to create an exception with builder pattern so I created the exception like this:

```
public class ApplicationException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8999932578270387947L;

    /** 
     * contains redundantly the HTTP status of the response sent back to the client in case of error, so that
     * the developer does not have to look into the response headers. If null a default 
     */
    Integer status;

    /** application specific error code */
    int code; 

    /** link documenting the exception */   
    String link;

    /** detailed error description for developers*/
    String developerMessage;    

    /**
     * 
     * @param status
     * @param code
     * @param message
     * @param developerMessage
     * @param link
     */
    protected ApplicationException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    ...

    public static Builder getBuilder(String message) {
        return new Builder(message);
    }   

    public static class Builder {
        private Integer status;
        private int code; 
        private String link;
        private String message;
        private String developerMessage;     

        public Builder(String message) {
            this.message = message;
        }

        public Builder status(int status) {
            this.status = status;
            return this;
        }


        public Builder code(int code) {
            this.code = code;
            return this;            
        }        

        public Builder developerMessage(String developerMessage) {
            this.developerMessage = developerMessage;
            return this;            
        }    

        public Builder link(String link) {
            this.link = link;
            return this;            
        }

        public ApplicationException build() {
            if (StringUtils.isBlank(message)) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("message cannot be null or empty");
            }

            if (StringUtils.isBlank(link)){
                link = AppConstants.API_SUPPORT_EMAIL;
            }

            ApplicationException created = new ApplicationException(message);
            created.status = status;
            created.code = code;
            created.developerMessage = developerMessage;
            created.link = link;

            return created;
        }        
    }
}
```

Now I can create an exception like this:

```
throw ApplicationException.getBuilder("This is the general error message")
    .status(404)
    .code(StatusCode.RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
    .developerMessage("The resource does not exist")
    .build();
```

The problem that I currently have is that I want to create different exceptions from this base exception. E.g. ValidationException which should extends from ApplicationException.

But the build() method already returns the concrete type ApplicationException. Currently I'm stuck because I'm not that familiar with using generics and if it is even possible within exception classes.

Comment: Do you need the compile-time type to be `ValidationException`, or do you only care about the execution-time type?

Comment: I think during execution-time would be enough if it makes thinks easier. I just don't want to work with only one general exception type. I want to indicate that during the validation of an object something went south..

Comment: Use a more [advanced builder pattern](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/228939/how-to-improve-upon-blochs-builder-pattern-to-make-it-more-appropriate-for-use). For inspiration take a look at Spring's [`HttpConfiguration`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-javaconfig-build/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/api-reference/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/HttpConfiguration.html).

Comment: And is there anything in the code you've given that would "tell" the builder to create a validation exception instead of a general application exception? (As an aside, your exception fields should be private and final, IMO.)

Comment: @ BoristheSpider 
thx I have a look into that

@ JonSkeet
No I don't have any indicator

Comment: Exceptions are simple, elegant and understood by the language. 

The reason I came here was to try to understand what would motivate using a Builder for Exceptions "I thought it would be nice" is probably not enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass `Class<? extends Exception>` to your `build` method, and use `newInstance()` inside to create the `Exception` object of the desired type:

```
throw ExceptionBuilder.getBuilder("This is the general error message")
    .status(404)
    .code(StatusCode.RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
    .developerMessage("The resource does not exist")
    .build(ValidationException.class); // <<== Choose type here
```

`Exception` object should not be created until the `build` call; inside the `build` you can do this:

```
Exception build(Class<? extends Exception> eClass) {
    Exception res = null;
    try {
        res = eClass.newInstance();
    } catch (.......) {
        // Catch the appropriate exceptions here
    }
    res.setAbc(); // Set values as needed
    ...
    return res;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this approach. 
And now I understand the question of Jon. I need the compile-time type. Otherwise all classes just indicate that they throw ApplicationException and you only see at compile Time that they throw the ValidationException..

Answer (score 2):

How many different exception subtypes are you dealing with?  If it's not too many, you could just make one `build()` method in your builder for each exception type:

```
throw ApplicationException.getBuilder("This is the general error message")
    .status(404)
    .code(StatusCode.RESOURCE_DOES_NOT_EXIST)
    .developerMessage("The resource does not exist")
    .buildValidation();  // or buildSomeOther()
```

It's not generic but it's very simple and will play nicely with IDE autocomplete

Comment: hey, 
well currently I don't think think that it will be too many. I already thought about it just to override the build() method for every exception class...

Comment: i think this approach and having additional build(exceptionClass) would do the trick.